# SQL Server - Variation auto increment based on primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

my scenario is this:

Say within an engineering environment, works for a job are quoted at £5,000. However after this a variation is made an additional cost is required for £500.

now within SQL Server I have a table, lets call it Costing. This is associated to the Customer table (1 to many) 1 Customer could have many costs...

Now my question is this... is it possible to auto increment a variation number within the CostingTable, baring in mind that the CostingID is already auto incrementing or is there a different approach I can take?

Example data:

[image]
ive already done all the costing calculations etc so this is no issue, its just if it is possible to automatically add one to the VariationNumber based upon the CustomerID... thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just to display it then use this:

```
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerId ORDER BY CostingId) AS Variation
FROM   Costing
```

But if you want to store it:

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerId ORDER BY CostingId) AS NewVariation
    FROM   Costing
)
UPDATE MyCTE 
SET    Variation = NewVariation
```

Comment: You need to play with the `ORDER BY` clause in the `ROW_NUMBER`. You should also provide the code that gets these results, so we may have a look.

Comment: works perfect, I was using the incorrect Order by (CostingID) Thanks for the help once again